# Unity isnt recognizing a component variable as a component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void AddComponent(Component component)
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<component>();
    }
```

the method is giving me
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5zUf.png)
and I'm wondering how to get it so it just works

Comment: 'component' is a variable but is used like a type

Answer (score 0):

You need let api know which type you want to add , this api not very smart to know your variable is what type. so just put in a type. not put in a variable.

```
SomeTypeOfCompoent : Compoent
{
}

gameObject.AddComponent<SomeTypeOfCompoent>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a component to be added that is of the same type as the variable you're passing you can do:

```
gameObject.AddComponent<typeof(component)>();
```

Alternatively you could change the method to

```
public void AddComponent(Type type) {
    gameObject.AddComponent<type>();
}
```

Since that would be using a Type parameter directly. To be honest though, if you're trying to do that, there's not really a need for your method at all. AddComponent already does that on it's own.

I suspect, however, that you're trying to copy the component including it's current data. If so, you can't do it in the way you are. Adding a component will just add that type of component with it's default settings. You can't Instantiate just a component either. Possible solutions for that are to Instantiate the entire gameobject it comes from, or make a method that adds a new component, then copies data one by one from the old component to the new one.